# Java help instance not working

Tags: java

My code:

```
public abstract class Address {

    public String myFirstname;
    public String myLastname;
    public String myStreet;
    public String myCity;
    public String myState;
    public int myZipcode;

    public Address(String firstname, String lastname, String street, String city, String state, int zipcode) {
        myFirstname = firstname;
        myLastname = lastname;
        myStreet = street;
        myCity = city;
        myState = state;
        myZipcode = zipcode;
    }

    public void fullAddress() {
        System.out.println(myFirstname + " " + myLastname);
        System.out.println(myStreet + "\n" + myCity + ", " + myState + " " + myZipcode);

    }

    public void setName(String f, String l) {
        myFirstname = f;
        myLastname = l;
    }

    public void setStreet(String s) {
        myStreet = s;
    }

    public void setCity(String c) {
        myCity = c;
    }

    public void setState(String sta) {
        myState = sta;
    }

    public void setzipcode(int z) {
        myZipcode = z;
    }
}

public class Boss extends Address {

    public int myRoomnumber;

    public Boss(String firstname, String lastname, String street, String city, String state, int zipcode, int roomnumber) {
        super(firstname, lastname, street, city, state, zipcode);
        myRoomnumber = roomnumber;
    }

    public void setRoomnumber(int room) {
        myRoomnumber = room;
    }

    public void fullAddress() //method overriding
    {
        System.out.println(myFirstname + " " + myLastname);
        System.out.println(myStreet + "\n" + myCity + ", " + myState + " " + myZipcode + "\n" + "Roomnumber:" + myRoomnumber);
    }

    class Worker extends Boss {

        public String mySection;

        public Worker(String firstname, String lastname, String street, String city, String state, int zipcode, int roomnumber, String section) {
            super(firstname, lastname, street, city, state, zipcode, roomnumber);
            mySection = section;
        }

        public void setRoomnumber(int room, String s) //method overloading
        {
            myRoomnumber = room;
            mySection = s;
        }

        public void fullAddress() {
            System.out.println(myFirstname + " " + myLastname);
            System.out.println(myStreet + "\n" + myCity + ", " + myState + " " + myZipcode + "\n" + "myRoomnumber:" + myRoomnumber + "-" + mySection);
        }
    }

    class Security extends Address {

        public int myRoomnumber;

        public Security(String firstname, String lastname, String street, String city, String state, int zipcode, int roomnumber) {
            super(firstname, lastname, street, city, state, zipcode);
            myRoomnumber = roomnumber;
        }

        public void fullAddress() {
            System.out.println(myFirstname + "" + myLastname + "\n" + "Roomnumber:" + myRoomnumber);
        }

    }

}
```

In my `main` method, when I create a `Boss` instance, it works and gives me `fulladdress` but when I try to create `Worker` instance, it gives me error.

```
Boss we = new Boss("asdf","sdfsdf","sdfsdf","sdfsdf","sdfsdfs",232,235);
we.fullAddress();

Worker ww = new Worker("asdf","sdfsdf","sdfsdf","sdfsdf","sdfsdfs",232,235,"sdfs");
ww.fullAddress();
```

Comment: please format properly

Comment: Don't be impatient. Use this site correctly for best results. If that means reading through the Help Center, **do it**.

Comment: Please indent your code, and *please* tell us the error!

Comment: Please clarify what "it gives me error" means.

Comment: I'm close-voting this as "typographical".  There's no `}` at the end of `Boss`, and there's an extra `}` at the end, so everything ends up looking like inner classes of `Boss`.  I beg you, while you're learning Java, put every class in its own file.

Answer (score 2):

`Work` is an "instance, inner class" of `Boss`, this means that `Worker` can't be instantiated without an instance of `Boss`

```
class Boss extends Address {

    //...

    class Worker extends Boss {
```

Start by removing `Worker` from inside `Boss` so that it's more of it's own class

```
class Boss extends Address {
    //...
}

class Worker extends Boss {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Boss.

```
Boss we = new Boss("asdf","sdfsdf","sdfsdf","sdfsdf","sdfsdfs",232,235);
we.fullAddress();

Worker ww = we.new Worker("asdf", "sdfsdf", "sdfsdf", "sdfsdf", "sdfsdfs", 232, 235, "sdfs");
ww.fullAddress();
```